# Problematic N-Tier logging with log4net

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net

I am currently developing series of web services in WCF using .NET 4.5. For my logging I have chosen log4net framework but I found that its a big problem to use it in my project design.

I have everything separated into projects like this :

- DataAccess
- Common
- etc. etc.
- ExternalServicesContracts
- ExternalServices
- ExternalServicesProxies
- InternalService

All of the services projects contains more services.

## Situation

I need my log files to look like this *ServiceName_YYYY_DDMM.log*.

So in the log4net config file i need to use different loggers per namespace of the web service. I can achieve it by using loggers like this :

For the first service :

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyFirstService));
```

And the same for the second service :

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MySecondService));
```

and then in config file I just point to them by loggers

```
<logger name="ExternalServices.MyFirstService">
  <appender-ref ref="FirstServiceAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="ExternalServices.MySecondService">
  <appender-ref ref="SecondServiceAppender"/>
</logger>
```

And in appenders

```
<appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="FirstServiceAppender">
  <file value="c:\temp\FirstService"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd.lo\g"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB"/>
....
</appender>

<appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="SecondServiceAppender">
  <file value="c:\temp\SecondService"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd.lo\g"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB"/>
....
</appender>
```

## Problem

After this change, I can`t see anything from my DataAccess and Common because I had to do the same strategy with classes inside the layer.

So the logger will be loaded the same way like this:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UsersProvider));
```

I could add another logger for both projects but I need the logs from it to be written inside the same file (the log file used by the caller).

## Question

I really cant separate the services into more projects because of the client.
Is there a way to use the same logger inside a library as the caller is using ? (So the DataAccess and Common writes logs into FirstServiceAppender when the service is using it.)

Or is there any pattern that would get me out of this situation ?

Comment: So, you want the logging from DataAccess and Common to be written into the "FirstServiceAppender" when DataAccess and Common are being used in the context of FirstService and to be written into "SecondServiceAppender" when DataAccess and Common are being used in the context of SecondService?  Is that right?

Comment: You are right, that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time to try this out right now, but this should be easier that you think it is.  You can try configuring log4net to have a dynamic file name based on a GlobalContext.Properties value.  In each service, put a value GlobalContext.Properties that "names" the service.  This should be ok as each service is essentially a separate process, so using the GlobalContext should not result in any conflicts.  This way you will need only one file target and your loggers can be configured very simply (just send the output to the one file target).

Configuration should be something like this:

```
<appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\temp\%property{Service}"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd.log"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="100MB"/>
....
</appender>

<root>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
```

In your code, when each service is initialized, put something like this:

```
GlobalContext.Properties["Service"] = "FirstService"; // for FirstService
GlobalContext.Properties["Service"] = "SecondService"; // for SecondService
```

Note that you must set the value into GlobalContext.Properties BEFORE anything else is done with log4net.  The best place would be in the static constructor of your application/service.

This configuration should all logs generated in "FirstService" to be written to the FirstService log file and all logs generated in "SecondService" to be written to the SecondService log.

Update:

```
<appender name="DynamicRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="c:\temp\%property{Service}" />
  <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd.lo\g" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5000KB" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true"/>
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <countDirection value="1"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%method] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right, this should work. I will test it today or tomorrow (I`m burried in other tasks) and we will see. Thanks for a great tip !

Comment: Ok, I just tested this approach and it writes into the right file without a problem. but the filename is wrong, eg. '(null)_2014_08_18.'. So I guess the property in the filename is not evaluated properly.

Comment: I did some experiments and got it to work better.  I am still getting an extra ".0" in the filename that I cannot explain.  It seems to be related to the date, but I don't know why.  You do have to be sure to put the "FirstService" value into GlobalContext.Properties["Service"] BEFORE the first logging statement.

Comment: Ok, I will give it another try. You can get rid of the .0 by using <datePattern value="_yyyy_MM_dd.lo\g"/> and <staticLogFileName value="false"/> so that is not a problem. Thanks again

Comment: So now its working. I had to set the GlobalContext in static constructor (even before I initialize the logger). Is it how you do it, or is it not necessary ? If I set the global context before first logging but after the LogManager.GetLogger call the filename is always null. Coould you please update that in your answer so I can mark you as answer ? Also thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I've updated to reflect your comments.  Feel free to make your own edit if anything is still not quite right.  Regarding your static constructor question..  I don't do this trick very often (except in response to StackOverflow questions ).  Apparently our experience in this question shows that it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass logger as a parameter for classes. So maybe your DataAccess classes should take a logger as a constructor parameter and use it for loggin. Then you could give a desired logger from outside.

Comment: I personally dont like passing log object through contructor of objects, but still upvoted because its a posible solution. Also I edited the question (DataAccess was just an example, the same problem is with the Common project). Thank you !

Comment: Also I will mark it as answer if there will be no other solution.